# Unable to assign value Matlab

Tags: matlab

Stuck in another MATLAB problem. Inside a loop `k=1:n_i`, I am running this statement. The `d(l)` in the `if d(l)>= -0.5` statement is returning `0` as its value. It is not even printing `d(l)`, rather gives `ans = 0`.

Any help will be appreciated. k=723 and n_i is 730 and d(k=723) is -1.52. When I separately print l which is 727 and then try d(727) i get the correct answer.

What I am trying is to basically check if d(k) < -1.5. If it is so, I am running a loop till the end remainder of the array to check for some d(k) >= -0.5

```
if d(k)<0

for l=k+1:n_i

    if d(l)>= -0.5
        d(l)               

        %p=p+(s-F(l,1)-b+E(l,1));
        tot=tot+1;
        break; 
    end
end
```

Comment: What does `d` contain?  If the `if` condition isn't running, that could mean that none of your values are `>= -0.5`.  Please provide expected inputs and outputs to the above code.

Comment: -1.530428872
-1.095485464
-0.739793411
-0.565244751
-0.251833542

shouldn't d take the last value?

Comment: just to add when i print l and then try d("the value of l i get post printing l) d(l) returns the right value

Comment: What is `n_i` here?  Are you sure `n_i` is the total number of elements in `d`?  Please put **all** of your code to run the problem.  Right now this code can't reproduce your error.  Specifically, we don't know what `F, b` and `E` are.

Comment: Depends on what k and n_i are.

Comment: k is 723 and n_i is 730

Comment: Any suggestions people?

Comment: Print `d(l)` right before you hit the if condition. More generally, if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, you don't even need a loop here, so read up on `find` and logical indexing.

Comment: find might be the way to go! One Q though. So I want to values in d after a  certain Index number. How do I incorporate that condition in find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?:

```
d=randn(1000,1);
n=length(d);
tot=9; % previous tot=9
for i=1:n
   if d(i)>=-0.5 
       tot=tot+1;
       break;
   end
end
disp(tot); %displaying 10
```

or this?:

```
i=(1:1000)';
d=randn(1000,1);
n=length(d);
itot=find(d>=-0.5);
plot(i,d); hold on;
plot(itot,d(itot))
```

Cheers...

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this. Using the find statement would list out all the values of d which are greater than -0.5. I want to go about finding the next d(l)>=-0.5. If so i would to record this 'l' and break of the loop.